# What's the number over the thumbnail?

Tags: youtube

[image: Numbers over video thumbnail]

I'm seeing those numbers over some videos. Usually the number is in the range from 1 to 9, but today I saw 112, or even <3

**Could someone cast some light over what this is?**

They only seem to appear over videos from subscribed channels, and not always appear, although they seem to be more frecuent over new videos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are just custom thumbnails. The user RevenantL0L has a template with the "mark" in his graphics program (probably Photoshop) which they use for every video.

Comment: So true. Now I realize that they only appear on his videos. Thanks!